# Conversion of image from blocks to original size

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, numpy

Hi I uploaded a 256*256 image and converted into 8 by 8 blocks by following the below procedure.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import loadmat
from PIL import Image
import scipy.misc as smp
from random import random
from math import exp

image = Image.open('jama.png').convert('L')

#image.show()
arrimag = np.array(image)
#print(arrimag.shape)
#print(arrimag)
row_windowsize = 8
column_windowsize = 8
imagelen = len(arrimag)
f = np.array([])
for row in range(0, imagelen, row_windowsize):
    for column in range(0, imagelen, column_windowsize):
        win = arrimag[row:row+row_windowsize, 
column:column+column_windowsize]
        window1 = np.zeros((64,1))
        window1 = win.ravel()
        window1 = window1.reshape(64,1)
        f = np.append(f,window1)
window = f.reshape((1024,64))
#print(window)
```

So, i will be grateful if someone can help me the inverse of this code so that I can recover my image from block of (8*8) to my original one (256*256)

NB: the new size of my image is Window (1024,64), i need to convert back to (256,256).

Comment: For one thing, `window1 = np.zeros((64,1))` does nothing. the new array gets discarded immediately.

Comment: Can you explain in detail in words what each step of your loop is supposed to do? I don't think you fully understand yourself. i may be wrong of course, but then  I'm unclear as to what your final goal is. It's certainly not just chunking into 8x8 segments

Comment: Please don't reply in the comments. Edit your question to be complete and use the comments to ping me after.

Comment: Does `f.reshape(32, 32, 8, 8).swapaxes(1, 2) .reshape(256, 256)` work by any chance?

Comment: Thanks, paul Panzer, it worked for me. you are intelligent.